# Add an extra get method in asp.net web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-http

I'm a very new comer to the asp.net web api world. I've got the basic understanding of get(), put(), post() and delete.

In my application, I require two more get() method. An explanation is given below-

```
public class StudentController : ApiController 
{
    public IEnumerable Get()
    {
        //returns all students.
    }

    //I would like to add this method=======================
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable GetClassSpecificStudents(string classId)
    {
        //want to return all students from an specific class.
    }

    //I also would like to add this method=======================
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable GetSectionSpecificStudents(string sectionId)
    {
        //want to return all students from an specific section.
    }

    public Student Get(string id) 
    {
         //returns specific student.
    }
}
```

There is already a `$http.get(..)` in angularjs controller.

My question is, how can I call the two additional `get()` methods from angular controller.

Comment: will all the urls be the same? you might wanna update the url to contain filters like /students/:filter/:filterId such as students/section/sectionId

Comment: @cbass - I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I haven't used asp.net mvc in forever. But you be able to do something like:

```
 public class StudentController : ApiController 
 {
    [Route("students")]
    public IEnumerable Get()
    {
    //returns all students.
    }

    //I would like to add this method=======================
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("students/class/{classId}")]
    public IEnumerable GetClassSpecificStudents(string classId)
    {
        //want to return all students from an specific class.
    }

    //I also would like to add this method=======================
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("students/section/{sectionId}")]
    public IEnumerable GetSectionSpecificStudents(string sectionId)
    {
        //want to return all students from an specific section.
    }
    [Route("students/{id}")]
    public Student Get(string id) 
    {
         //returns specific student.
    }
}
```

You could also specify  routes in the routeconfig like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "students",
    url: "students/class/{classId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "GetClassSpecificStudents", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You have to try for your self. And you can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) and [here](http://attributerouting.net/).

Not that you have your specified routes you can add angular $http.gets for each route.

```
var url = "whateverdoma.in/students/"
$http.get(url)
   .success()
   .error()

var url = "whateverdoma.in/students/class/" + classId;
$http.get(url)
   .success()
   .error()

var url = "whateverdoma.in/students/filter/" + filterId;
$http.get(url)
   .success()
   .error()
```

Comment: You have explained well. The scenario is clear to me. Thanks a lot. +1.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is write costum angular resource method, to call your API.

1. Use angular $resource and not $http - > it is the more common usage (and more REST  oriented:  $resource wraps $http for use in RESTful web API scenarios).
2. [Read about it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)
3. Find how to add a resource to the $resource service.

   Here is an example:

   ```
   .factory('Store', function ($resource, hostUrl) {
   var url = hostUrl + '/api/v3/store/';

   return $resource("", {  storeId: '@storeId' }, {            
       getSpecific: {
           method: 'GET',
           url: hostUrl + '/api/v3/store-specific/:storeId'
       }
   });
   ```

   })